# How molecules gain energy from electromagnetic radiation?

Tags: particle-physics, atomic-physics, atmospheric-science, plasma-physics, applied-physics

Heat comes from the sun as electromagnetic radiation. It is the principal source of heat on earth. but how this radiation is absorbed by molecules? How they gain kinetic energy from it?

Comment: Molecules are made of charged particles. Charged particles interact with the electromagnetic field.

Comment: More specifically, molecules are quantum objects with discrete vibrational and rotational states.  Heat radiation excites these states.

Comment: By transfer of momentum. if you haven't already, you should read [QED by Feynman](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/QED:_The_Strange_Theory_of_Light_and_Matter)

Comment: in parallel to John's answer see my answer here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/305696/how-molecules-radiate-heat-as-electromagnetic-wave/305828#305828

Answer (score 1):

Sunlight does not heat the atmosphere directly because its wavelength lies in a range of frequencies that gas molecules cannot absorb. The primary mechanism for heating the atmosphere is that the sunlight strikes the ground or sea and heats it up. The heat is then transferred to the atmosphere by convection, or in the case of the sea evaporation of water plays an important role as well.

But radiation can and does heat gases. For example infrared light is absorbed by carbon dioxide in the atmosphere leading to the greenhouse effect, and it's interesting to consider how this happens.

Light, whether visible, infra-red or any other frequency, is an electromagnetic wave so it is a combination of an oscillating electric and magnetic field - for our purposes we can ignore the magnetic field and consider only the electric field.

If a gas molecule has an electric dipole moment (e.g. carbon dioxide) then the electric dipole moment of the gas molecule can interact with the oscillating electric field of the light, and this allows energy to be transferred between the light and the gas molecule. Specifically the light can make the molecule vibrate. If this vibrating gas molecule collides with another gas molecule the vibrational energy can be converted to kinetic energy so the two molecules separate with greater kinetic energy then they had before they collided. And increased kinetic energy means increased temperature.

I've simplified this because the interaction of the light and molecule is described by quantum mechanics. The vibrational and rotational energy levels of the molecule are quantised and the molecule can only absorb a photon of light if the energy of the light matches a [rovibrational transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational%E2%80%93vibrational_spectroscopy) in the gas molecule. That's why carbon dioxide will absorb certain frequencies of infra-red but not visible light. However the overall process is the same as I described in the previous paragraph. A photon of light is absorbed and makes the molecule vibrate (and rotate), and the vibrating molecule subsequently collides with another molecule and converts the vibrational energy to translational energy.